# Unity Shader Graph - Normal From Height not supported in HDRP DXR

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

When making a shader graph with HDRP and ray tracing 2021LTS, using the node *Normal From Height*, i got this error :

```
'Normal From Height' node is not supported in ray tracing, please provide an alternate implementation, relying for instance on the 'Raytracing Quality' keyword Compiling Subshader: 1, Pass: VisibilityDXR, RayTracing program with _BLENDMODE_OFF...
```

How to implementation alternative solution with Custom Function or SubGraph ?

Answer (score 0):

This might not help much, but it might help a bit - I know it works on the Amplify shader graph. I just used it and I am also using 2021 LTS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).